# Calculating the control point of Curve using a given point

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to develop a Quadratic Bezier Curve using the `graphics.curveTo()` method. Initially when I drag mouse to draw the shape, I use start point and end point of mouse to draw the curve line. I assume control point at any position below or up to the line. An draw the curve using this control point. some what like:-

```
graphics.move(startPoint.x,startPoint.y);

graphics.curveTo(controlPoint.x, controlPoint.y, 

endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
```

Now I add a tip on this curve segment. I have x and y position of tip. I want to change the curve segment by dragging tip. but now I don't have the exact control point according to tip position. If I use tip coordinate as control point it reduce the height of curve and now tip does not lie on the curve segment. What I have to do is calculate the exact control point on the basis of tip coordinate. But I failed to get this point. Please help me to get this control point.

Answer (score 0):

This page shows how to draw a quadratic bezier curve. It has a demo and source code as well.
http://philippe.elsass.me/2009/06/as3-parametric-path-drawing/